# Filter on date in PowerQuery (PowerBI)

Tags: filter, powerquery

I'm currently getting to much data from my cosmosDB, which I want to reduce to the last 8 weeks.

How can I filter in PowerQuery to get the last 8 weeks based on my **date column.**

This is my powerquery to get the data:

```
let
    Source = DocumentDB.Contents("https://xxx.xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
    #"Expanded Document" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "Document", {"$v"}, {"Document.$v"}),
    #"Expanded Document.$v" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Document", "Document.$v", {"date"}, {"Document.$v.date"}),
    #"Expanded Document.$v.date" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Document.$v", "Document.$v.date", {"$v"}, {"Document.$v.date.$v"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Document.$v.date",{{"Document.$v.date.$v", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

And this is how the data is in my CosmosDB:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c6144bdf7ce070001acc213"),
"date" : {
    "$date" : 1549792055030
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do all the work on your end (maybe the server can do some/all of it):

- Assuming the `1549792055030` (shown in example) is a Unix timestamp expressed in milliseconds, to convert to a `datetime` in Power Query, try something like: `#datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, 1549792055030/1000)`
- You seem to expand a record field named `$v` (which itself was nested within a field named `date`, which itself was nested within a field named `$v`) in your `M` code, but `$v` is not shown as being present in the structure. I mention this as it's confusing to know whether to follow your `M` code or the structure. I'm going to assume that you have `$v` field, which contains a `date` field, which itself contains a `$date` field. To get at the nested Unix timestamp, you could try something like: `someRecord[#"$v"][date][#"$date"]`
- Since you're interested in only the last 8 weeks, you could test for something like: `Date.IsInPreviousNWeeks(DateTime.AddZone(someDatetime, 0), 8)`. (You could also do it the other way, by converting `8 weeks ago before now` to a Unix timestamp and then filter for timestamps `>=` to the value you've worked out.)

Putting the above together, we might get some `M` code that looks like:

```
let
    Source = DocumentDB.Contents("https://xxx.xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
    filterDates = Table.SelectRows(Source, each
        let
            millisecondsSinceEpoch = Number.From([document][#"$v"][date][#"$date"]),
            toDatetime = #datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, millisecondsSinceEpoch/1000),
            toFilter = Date.IsInPreviousNWeeks(DateTime.AddZone(toDatetime, 0), 8)
        in toFilter
    )
in filterDates
```

---

The code above may be functional (hopefully) but, conceptually, it might not be the right way to do it. I am not familiar with the function `DocumentDB.Contents`, but this link (https://www.powerquery.io/accessing-data/document-db/documentdb.contents) suggests it has these parameters:

> function (**url** as text, optional **database** as nullable any, optional
>   **collection** as nullable any, optional **options** as nullable record) as
>   table

and it goes on to say:

> *if the field Query is specified in the options record the results of
>   the query being executed on either the specified database and/or
>   collection will be returned.*

What I understand this to mean is that if you change your first line to something like:

```
Source = DocumentDB.Contents("https://xxx.xxx", "xxx", "xxx", [Query = "..."])
```

and the query you specify in `"..."` is understood by the server (presume the query needs be in Cosmos DB's native query language), only the last 8 weeks' worth of data will be returned to you (meaning less data needs sending and less work for you). As I said, I'm unfamiliar with Azure Cosmos DB, so I can't really comment further. But this seems the better way of doing it.